# package ‘get_ontology’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a gene ontology analysis on my single cell seq dataset in R. However R keeps giving me the error: package ‘get_ontology’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3). I have already tried two different versions:4.0.0 and 3.6.0, but these two versions also gave this error. The main package ontologyIndex does work for the version 3.6.3. Is there another version I could try, or do people have any tips for the get_ontology function?

Comment: `get_ontology` is not a package, it's a function in a package (`ontologyIndex`). You must install the *package* and load it with `library(ontologyIndex)` before using the *function*. Also, what have you tried? What code have you run exactly?

Comment: R is correct insofar as there is no package `get_ontology`. There is a function `get_ontology` provided by the package `ontologyIndex`. It seems you try to load the function with `library(get_ontology)` what doesn't work (because it's a function).

Comment: I have run the code install.packages(get_ontology). Butnow I have read that the get_ontology is not a package but a function :) The reason I tried this was because I got this error Error in get_ontology(x, name = paste(names(df.list[i]), "Pathways for top 100 genes",  : 
  unused arguments (name = paste(names(df.list[i]), "Pathways for top 100 genes", sep = " "), return.data = T, full_GSEA = F)

Comment: , after I run this code:   x <- data.frame(gene = rownames(df.list[[i]]), avg_logFC = 0)
    get_ontology(x, name = paste("Cluster", names(df.list[i]), "Pathways for top 100 genes", sep = " "), return.data = T, full_GSEA = F)